# What are differences between "advice" and "advise"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, word-usage

When we can use advice instead of advise? Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

“Advice” is a noun. “Advise” is a verb.

As simple as that.

Comment: Their meaning are same or different?

Comment: The same. Only difference is in the part of speech. 

Example: 

Let me give you some advice. I advise you to exercise regularly and to wake up early.

Comment: Also, generally speaking, "advice" is an uncountable noun. So we give someone "a piece of or some"advice.

Comment: Also "advice" is licensed by OED as a [count noun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55693/advice-vs-an-advice) (admittedly rare in most registers).

Comment: I had no idea that "advice" is licensed as a count noun. My Longman, Oxford, and Cambridge dictionaries all say that it is a non-count noun. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: It's best to check for previous (and perhaps more accurate) answers.

Comment: So you need to go through my comment once again. I did check it in 3 different dictionaries including Oxford but all have licensed "advice" as an uncountable noun. Nothing more accurate than this.

Comment: You obviously don't know that the OED is not the ODO (which is what I assume you mean by 'Oxford'. Have you looked at this [previous answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55693/advice-vs-an-advice/129231#129231) yet, where Barrie England has already been more accurate than 'this'? The other dictionaries you cite don't give the complete picture.

Comment: As far as I know OED stands for Oxford English Dictionary.http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/what-are-the-main-differences-between-the-oed-and-odo

Comment: To quote Barrie, "The OED records _advice_ as a count noun, but comments that it is ‘Now chiefly Caribbean and South Asian’, although there are citations from a variety of sources from the fifteenth century onwards." The full, not condensed version.

Comment: In modern usage advice is licensed as a non-count noun and I haven't seen it being used as a count noun. So what's the point in providing OP with information which as you said is "rare in most registers"?

Comment: I'm not, in the first instance – I'm correcting your answer: Also "advice" is rarely used other than as an uncountable noun. Though perhaps golnaz (or some visitor) has come across the unusual count usage. It's not incorrect.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your "advice"!