# What does "scored heavily against" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "scored heavily against" mean? As in the following sentence.

> A scored heavily against B in that TV encounter.

Update:

Thanks for the answer. In the book that I'm reading, it was not clear to me that who got the better score. Now it's confirmed that it's A. This gives me a better understanding of the author's perspective.

Comment: It's [this sense](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/heavily): Adv. 1. **heavily** - to a considerable degree; "he relied heavily on others' data" to a great extent [Based on WordNet 3.0, Farlex clipart collection. © 2003-2012 Princeton University, Farlex Inc.] //  **heavily**  adv 6. in large amounts: _to rain heavily_ . [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc.] 'He scored heavily against Trump' means 'He scored a lot of points in the frame/s he played against Trump'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thank you. Could you move your comment into an answer? Therefore I would mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: No; almost certainly, it would better as an ELL question than an ELU question. You should at least have posted some dictionary research here, even if you didn't spot the sense involved.

Comment: That's a good advice. Also I didn't even know there is a ELL forum. Thanks for pointing them out!

Comment: A good _piece of_ advice!

Comment: @Edwin Though no one uses it this way anymore, it used to be normal and proper to use [advice as a count noun](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55693/advice-vs-an-advice), as in "*an advice*".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> What does "scored heavily against" mean?

If RealMadrid  scored heavily against Barcelona it means that it won 
5 - 0, 7 - 2 etc

It means that it scored many points, and particularly that the *difference* is large.